# Is it possible to encrypt a string using a jar library in php?

Tags: java, php, html, encryption, jar

Im integrating a payment gateway.The processor has given me a jar file with which they wanted me to encrypt the card data.

This is th sample java code they have given

```
Data =cardNumber|cvv|expYear(4digit)|expMonth
And it should be encrypted with the jar as
SecureCardData sd = new SecureCardData();
String encCardData = sd.encryptData(Data);

Code to encrypt the data is as follows:
String Data = "1800585544448888|445|2015|11";
SecureCardData sd = new SecureCardData();
String encCardData = sd.encryptData(Data);
String cardHname = “Card Holder Name”;
String mdd=”channelid=INT|carddata=” + encCardData +”|cardhname=”+cardHname;
```

But right now Iam using php as my server side language.
How will it be possible to encrypt using a jar library in a php file?

Please help

Comment: If they have a PHP library, that would be so much easier.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use the jar in php?

Comment: Not directly no, you could create a Java CLI application and execute that using `java -jar payment.jar --encrypt [arguments]`. Apache has a command line parser. Note that personally I would not recommend using PHP for online payments, but that's just me.